# Casing in CSS or SASS alone

Tags: css, saas

I have text coming up from backend as iaas, paas, saas etc which I need to convert to IaaS, PaaS and SaaS. How do we do it with CSS alone?

Comment: If that text is coming from a backend, why not run this there?

Comment: Since there is no :last-letter selector in css you cant capitalize the text and set the last letter uppercase. I would just remove the last letter with javascript, capitalize the Text and add an uppercase S to it.

Comment: The last letter is not possible with CSS.

Comment: You need to use native JS to do this.